# ListBox.ScrollIntoView() does not seem to work in WP7

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to move the listbox scrollbar to the bottom whenever a new item is added to the itemssource, but `ScrollIntoView()` doesn't seem to do anything if I pass it either a reference to the newly added item, or the index of it. Has anyone gotten this to work, or have any other suggestions as to how I could scroll the listbox down to the bottom?

Some code:

```
    void Actions_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //if a new item was added, set it to the selected item
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            MainListBox.SelectedIndex = e.NewStartingIndex;

            //MainListBox.ScrollIntoView(MainListBox.Items.Last());     //todo: this doesnt seem to work
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

MSDN says:

When the contents of the ItemsSource collection changes, particularly if many items are added to or removed from the collection, you may need to call UpdateLayout() prior to calling ScrollIntoView for the specified item to scroll into the viewport.

Could that be your problem?

Answer (score 5):

THIS is the answer:

http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/wpf-listview-scrollintoview.html

In a few words: the items are loaded into the ListBox asynchronously, so if you call ScrollIntoView() within the CollectionChanged event (or similar) it will not have any items yet, so no scrolling.

Hope it helps, it surely helped me! ;-)

Comment: for MVVM apps, this is the REAL answer

Answer (score 3):

`ScrollIntoView` definitely works. I just added an application button to an empty databound app and doing the following on button click caused the list to scroll.

```
MainListBox.ScrollIntoView(MainListBox.Items.Last());
```

Could be an issue with an event on `selectionChanged`? Do you have anything hooked up to that?
Does the ScrollIntoView work if you don't set the selected item?

Comment: Hi Matt, where does the .Last() method come from? I add a new item to my collection and am not aware of the index - I don't have this method on my Items class?

Comment: @Rodney `.Last()` is an extension method on IEnumerable<T> in System.Linq

Comment: `lb.ScrollIntoView(lb.Items[lb.Items.Count-1])` also works. I don't know the contracts on `ItemCollection`, but I'd make an educated guess the `.Last()` extension method would be O(n) and direct indexing would be O(1) if the collection kept track of the number of elements. I could totally be wrong about this, and `.Last()` is clearly less prone to typos.

Answer (score -2):

you can insert the new item always on the top by

yourItemList.Insert(0, item);

thus no need for ScrollIntoView. May be this will help!!