# XMAL ListView footer scrolls to footer programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a ListView with footer in my window phone application.
How can I programmatically scroll the ListView so that the footer is visible?

Thank you.

Comment: There's a method ScrollIntoView() for take a peek here, it's similar to use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904877/listbox-scrollintoview-does-not-seem-to-work-in-wp7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, this actually works:

```cs
ListView myListView = ...
myListView.ScrollIntoView(myListView.Footer);
```

I expected `ScrollIntoView()` to only accept list items, but it accepts the footer (and header, I guess) too.

Comment: The footer and header are ListView items. Hence why you set them through a DataTemplate.